# O que é Batch Script?

Tags: batch, bat

Comecei a estudar sobre Batch e surgiu uma dúvida na minha cabeça sobre ele ser ou não ser uma **linguagem de programação**.

Fiz uma pesquisa na internet sobre esse assunto e algumas pessoas dizem que não, outros dizem que sim e outros dizem que é uma "espécie" de linguagem.

O que eu quero saber é: o exatamente é Batch Script e qual seria a diferença entre ele e o CMD ?

Comment: Já deu uma lida nas tags?

Comment: Sim eu li e é a mesma coisa que encontrei na internet: ""Batch", também chamado como “processamento em lote”, refere-se a(s) execução(ões) de um ou mais comandos, podendo ser interno, e/ou externo. Como, também, pode(m) conter(em) chamada(s) de programa(s), em um computador, para execuções diversas, com ou sem a interação do usuário, para atender ao processamento desejado".  Não sei se sou eu que não estou entendendo, mas ainda assim estou com a dúvida se é uma linguagem ou apenas uma ferramenta para automatizar tarefas simples. Eu ficaria feliz se falasse apenas se é ou não um linguagem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um arquivo batch é um termo para um aquivo "em lote", significa que ele contém um lote de informação a ser processada.
É um termo antigo, não está necessariamente associado a um programa ou script, pode ser um lote de informações, como dados a serem incluidos/alterados num banco de dados ou processados de alguma maneira, essa é a ideia.

Um arquivo em lote .BAT é um arquivo de lotes de comandos do prompt do DOS, como `copy` e `ren`.

É chamado de arquivo em lote pois os comandos do DOS não são reconhecidos como uma linguagem de programação (como `C++` por exemplo), nem um linguagem de script (como `Javascript` por exemplo).
Já li em alguns lugares ser chamada de *crippled language*, que literalmente significa um linguagem aleijada, ou seja, uma linguagem que "faltam coisas" para ser uma linguagem.

Portanto, `CMD` tem vários comandos, que não são necessariamente uma linguagem, e um `BATCH` é um lote, uma sequencia desses comandos (por exemplo criar um diretório e copiar arquivos para lá) salvos num arquivo `.BAT` que pode ser executado pelo sistema operacional.